# Get Row and Column Names (argmax) for max entry in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, feature-selection

df.idxmax() returns max along an axis (row or columns), but I want arg_max(df) over the full dataframe, which returns a tuple (row,column).

The use case I have in mind is feature selection, wherein I have a correlation matrix and want to "recursively" remove features with highest correlation. I preprocess the correlation matrix to consider its absolute values and set the diagonal elements to -1. Then I propose to use rec_drop, which recursively drops one amongst the feature-pair that has the highest correlation (subject to a cutoff: max_allowed_correlation), and returns the final list of features. E.g.:

```
S = S.abs()
np.fill_diagonal(S.values,-1) # so that max can't be on the diagonal now
S = rec_drop(S,max_allowed_correlation=0.95)

def rec_drop(S, max_allowed_correlation=0.99):
    max_corr = S.max().max()
    if max_corr<max_allowed_correlation: # base case for recursion
         return S.columns.tolist() 
    row,col = arg_max(S)  # row and col are distinct features - max can't be on the diagonal
    S = S.drop(row).drop(row,axis=1) # removing one of the features from S
    return rec_drop(S, max_allowed_correlation)
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that all your pandas table is numerical, something you can do is transform to its numpy interpretation and extract maximum locations from there. However, numpy's `argmax` works on the flattened data, so you will need to work around:

```
# Synthetic data
>>> table = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,3))
>>> table
          0         1         2
0  0.367720  0.235935  0.278112
1  0.645146  0.187421  0.324257
2  0.644926  0.861077  0.460296
3  0.035064  0.369187  0.165278
4  0.270208  0.782411  0.690871

[5 rows x 3 columns
```

Transform table to numpy data and calculate argmax:

```
>>> data = table.as_matrix()
>>> amax = data.argmax() # 7 in this case
>>> row, col = (amax//data.shape[1], amax%data.shape[1])
>>> row, col
(2, 1)
```